# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null for certain images

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream, okhttp, bitmapfactory

Im making a `synchronous` network request using `okhttp3` to an endpoint that responses with an image file.

As soon as the `synchronous` network request using `okhttp3` is completed I try to convert the `response.body()` into a `Bitmap` using an `Inputstream` and `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`. The `Bitmap` is saved to a class variable `Bitmap bitmap;`

While for some images this works, but for others they don't - the `bitmap` returns `null` and I can't figure out why?

```
    ....
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private Response networkFetchAsset(String path, String[] params){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(myURL)
            .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.print(response);
            InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            System.out.print(bitmap);
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Experiencing the same problem.